# What's the most efficient way to return to previous state when another link is clicked outside the element? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a link which when clicked will change its state like so:

```
$('.last_link').bind("click", function() {
     $(this).css({"color" : "#BBB", "cursor" : "default"});
});
```

However, if I click another link within that link set, it still retains that state. What I like to happen is for the link to go back to its previous state when I click another link.

Instead of re-setting the previous state of .last-link when I click the other links, is there a better, more efficient way to just revert back to this selector's original state?

(Edit: Let's say I have other methods inside that function apart from .css() like I have a chain of methods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.high-state {
    color: #BBB;
    cursor: default;
}

a {
   color: blue;
   cursor: pointer;
}

$("a").click(function() {
    $(".high-state").removeClass('high-state');
    $(this).addClass('high-state');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/majidf/4r6XN/

Comment: and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pkxpL/) you can watch this in action. I just was too slow setting up an example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've set the style using css rather than the style attribute you can just do `$('.last_link').removeAttr('style')`

This is because calling .css() sets the value of the style attribute so if you remove it the state will be reverted.

http://jsfiddle.net/jQ2xw/

Comment: Yes I think that's a shorter way. However, I edited my question to include a chain of methods instead of just one method.

Comment: @catandmouse I'm not sure exactly what difference that makes?